# Asyncio .create_task() not running function passed in

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a program that does several timer-related things in python and I need to make it so Asyncio creates a task (without waiting for it) by calling another function with `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(timer_function(my_parameters))`, I've used this before in another project and it worked just fine, however, in this case, it ends up not calling `timer_function()` like it should and I suspect that it happens because it's inside loops or something related to the project structure. I could not find anything that worked as for now, only using `await` managed to call the function, but that ended up not making it run in parallel. The project structure is as follows:

```
async def timer_function(my_parameters):

   print('Timer_Function called')
   
   # Do stuff with the parameters

   asyncio.sleep(time_based_on_those_parameters)

   # Finish doing some other things



# Note: final() doesn't need to be async, I only made it so
# to try and test some fixes
async def final(parameters):  

   # Do stuff

   while True:  # This part loops forever every minute

      # Do stuff

      for i in range(my_range):

         if some_condition_a:

            asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(timer_function(my_parameters))

            print('Condition A met')

         if some_condition_b:

            asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(timer_function(some_different_parameters)

            print('Condition B met')

         # Do some other stuff

   sleep(60)
```

Once I run the code, all that gets printed when those conditions are met is

`>>> Condition met`

but what I expected to see is both

```
>>> Condition met
>>> Timer function called
```

I then put `await` before the create_task part all that gets printed at the time is

```
>>> Timer function called
```

And then only when the timer runs out and does what it needs to do is when `>>> Condition met`
gets printed. Is there a way to change this structure to accomodate Asyncio or something else I could try?

**EDIT**: I found a workaround using `threading` instead of `asyncio`. The code is now like this:

```
def timer_function(my_parameters): # Sync method now

   print('Timer_Function called')
   
   # Do stuff with the parameters

   sleep(time_based_on_those_parameters) # No longer asyncio.sleep()

   # Finish doing some other things



def final(parameters):  

   # Do stuff

   threads = []

   while True:  # This part loops forever every minute

      # Do stuff

      for i in range(my_range):

         if some_condition_a:

             t = threading.Thread(target=timer_function, args=(my_parameters))
             threads.append(t)
             t.start()          

             print('Condition A met')

         if some_condition_b:

            t = threading.Thread(target=timer_function, args=(my_parameters))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

            print('Condition B met')

         # Do some other stuff

   sleep(60)
```

This now works as intended, so for me I no longer need to fix this issue, however if anyone knows why Asyncio doesn't do that when in this structure please let me know, as someone may have this same issue in the future. (I checked on another project I made and
`asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(timer_function(my_parameters))`
can be called without awaiting, the difference is that in this case it's inside a `while True` and a `for` loop, and on that case that worked it was simply called once on an event listener)

Comment: Are you testing it in Jupiter notebook? Or a .py file?, Because Jupiter runs their async loop and could lose your output.

Comment: @Cristian Contrera it's a .py file

Comment: `asyncio.sleep()` must be awaited, so it should be `await asyncio.sleep(time_based_on_those_parameters)`. Also, `sleep(60)` looks wrong, perhaps it should also be `await asyncio.sleep(60)`? (Currently it's outside the loop, not sure if that's intended.) Note that the tasks you created will start executing only once you await something and thereby give back control to the event loop, which your `while` loop doesn't appear to do.

Comment: `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(timer_function(my_parameters))` just creates task but not executes so you need to awaits or appends all tasks and awaits after. Execution happens in threading because you had put `t.start()` check here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

Comment: @tard yes, using ```await``` ran the method but halted everything else (because it waits for them to finish everything before proceeding), I think it's better that I used threading as they open and close methods while continuing the loop

Comment: if you immediately `await`, it halts but if you collect them all(in array) and execute after the loop ends these tasks will run on different threads and don't conflicts with or halt each other

Answer (score 0):

I am only starting to work with asyncio but my guess is that `create_task` is not running anything, you could try `run_until_complete` instead

Comment: it is recommended to add more details to the answer explaining why you think this will solve OP's problem. Please check this link on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)